# If statement not working and properties not working laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an e-commerce site and while checking out people can use promocode if they have one.

That promocode table consist:

```
id , name , description , valid_from , valid_till , discount
```

and I have added one more column called `orders_limit`-
In my checkout controller I have something like this

CheckoutController.php

```
if ($request->promo['promoCode']) {
    $promo = CheckOrder::checkPromo($request->promo);
    if ($promo == null) {
        return response()->json(['Error' => "Invalid Promo Code"]);
    }
}
```

CheckOrder.php looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Models\Admin\Coupon;
use App\Models\FrontEnd\Order;

class CheckOrder
{
    public static function checkPromo($promo)
    {
        $coupon = Coupon::where('name', $promo['promoCode'])->first();
        if ($coupon->orders_limit == null) {
            if ($coupon->isValid()) {
                return $coupon;               
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But in this case , the first if condition is greater true wheather the `orders_limit` is null or not anyway

This is my blade file

```
<div class="mt-4">
    <a class="font-12 text-uppercase text-primary" href="#">User promo code ? <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></a>
    <form class="mt-3 form-inline">
        <div class="form-group m-auto">
            <input type="text" class="form-control font-12 m-auto border-radius-0" id="promoCode" placeholder="Code here" v-model.lazy="promo.promoCode" @change="checkPromo()">
            <button class="btn bg-theme-color text-white border-radius-0" @click.stop.prevent="checkPromo()">GO</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you should `dd($coupon->orders_limit)`. Don't doubt the `if`. it's working since inception. you can also check like `if($coupan && empty($coupon->order_limit)){`.

Comment: How do you submit this form?

Comment: what is it supposed to mean if `$coupon->orders_limit` is `null`, in your situation?

Comment: Unclear what you asking for

Answer (score 2):

This can return `null`:

```
$coupon = Coupon::where('name', $promo['promoCode'])->first();
```

If you try to access properties on `$coupon` that would be "trying to access property of a non-object", because it is `null`. You need to check for this.

If I pass you a non existing promocode then `$coupon` will be `null`.